# Bitwise operation and type conversion error

Tags: c#, arrays, bit-manipulation

I am unpacking a `byte[] content` into a bunch of fields.  Most of it directly maps from field to type (eg 4 bytes = Uint32).  There are some that are fields packed into a byte.  eg 8 bools, or 2bits + 4 bits + bool + bool.  In the constructor below I try to parse the `content` into class properties.

```
public RFTagLost(byte[] content)
{
    byte flags1;
    UInt16 flags2;

    int i = 0;

    GatewaySerial = BitConverter.ToUInt32(content, i);
    i += sizeof(UInt32);

    SerialNumber = BitConverter.ToUInt32(content, i);
    i += sizeof(UInt32);

    Token = BitConverter.ToUInt32(content, i);
    i += sizeof(UInt32);

    flags1 = content[i];
    i += sizeof(byte);
    // TODO parse flags
    GatewayMode = (byte)((flags1 >> 0) & 3);            // 2 bits
    LinkType = (byte)((flags1 >> 2) & 3);               // 2 bits
    Reserved = (byte)((flags1 >> 4) & 15);              // 4 bits

    TagType = content[i];
    i += sizeof(byte);

    flags2 = BitConverter.ToUInt16(content, i);
    i += sizeof(UInt16);
    LastSeen = (UInt16)((flags2 >> 0) & 32767);           // 15 bits
    LastSeenInMinutes = (bool)((flags2 >> 15) & 1);     // 1 bit
}
```

I was having problems with the shift and mask operations returning an int.  I finally worked out that despite flag1 being a byte, bitwise was returning an int that was causing my assign to property to fail.  Same with flag2.

Now my error is that

> Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'

This is when trying to extract the last field.  It's the last bit in a UInt16

Am I doing the right thing to extract these bit fields.  What do I do to make `bool LastSeenInMinutes` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert an int to a bool, you can just test the result for equality with 1 or 0.

```
LastSeenInMinutes = ((flags2 >> 15) & 1) == 1;
```